# Objective-C Populating a table view with an instance of NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, xml, macos, nsdictionary, nstableview

i need some help i want to load an xml file into a table view this is what i have so far, could anyone explain to me how to do this. I think it would involve bindings too which i know a bit about.

```
NSString* libraryPath = @"~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music Library.xml";
NSDictionary* musicLibrary = [ NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: libraryPath ];
```

Thanks, Sami.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `NSXMLDocument` to parse the XML file, it might be a little easier to do than implement an `NSXMLParser.` Here's an example (untested).

```
- (void) parseItunesLibrary {
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSString* libraryPath = nil;

    // better way to get the iTunes database file (in case library was moved)
    NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSDictionary* iAppsDict = [defaults persistentDomainForName:@"com.apple.iApps"];
    NSArray* itunesDBPath = [iAppsDict objectForKey:@"iTunesRecentDatabasePaths"];
    if( [itunesDBPath count] > 0 ) {
        libraryPath = [[itunesDBPath objectAtIndex: 0] stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
    }   

    NSData* libraryData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:libraryPath];
    NSXMLDocument* libraryDoc = [[NSXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:libraryData options:NSXMLDocumentTidyXML error:&error];
    // handle error before continuing here
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        [libraryDoc release];
        return;
    }

    NSXMLElement* root = [libraryDoc rootElement];
    [libraryDoc release];

    // assuming you wanted an array of the songs you can get them like this
    NSArray* songsArray = [root nodesForXPath:@".//dict/dict/dict" error:nil];

   // to access the different song elements you can do something like this
    for(NSXMLElement* song in songsArray) {
        NSString* songArtist = [[[song nodesForXPath:@"./Artist" error:nil] lastObject] stringValue];
    }
}
```

Once you have this data, you can put it in an `NSTableView` any way you like. Look at using a table datasource in the [NSTableView Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/Tasks/UsingTableDataSource.html).

Comment: Hm I don't remember lol, but I did implement something similar. Other than potential syntax errors, this should still be valid.